# How to handle two collection views inside two container views

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I have a view controller with segmented view controller at top and then two container views placed upon another. I will be hiding and showing them based upon selection from segmented controller.

Have a look at screenshot: [2ContainerViews_2childViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QSCl.png)

Each child view has collection view on it. Now i am not sure how to start i.e

- how to take these two collection views along?
- Can i link both of these child views and hence collection views to
  single class? or do i have to implement three classes, one for main
  view controller, and two for collection views on child views
  separately?

Please help. I will be thankful.

Comment: If you have *"two container views placed upon another"* you are somewhat defeating the purpose of using container views. Regardless, there are several ways you could do this. Depending on how much different data logic and/or appearance you have between "Providing" and "Seeking" you may just want one controller handling the collection view, but use different classes to provide the data and the delegate. Have you tried implementing any code yet?

Comment: No i have not yet started any implementation. I was confused about how and where to start doing this. Providing and Seeking both shows tabs with posts in collection view cells. Regarding container views placed upon one another, i found this here: [link](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/). I am doing same i.e placing both above one another and changing alpha views to make them show/hide. Can you please tell me how should i go with container views if not above one another? Because i think container view can have one child only.

Comment: OK - that article appears to use two `UIViewControllers` as the "child" controllers... I think you need to just start working on your code, and ask specific questions when you run into problems. It is next to impossible for someone to answer a question like "how should I do something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've given here, it sounds like these two collection views are mutually exclusive (you are only displaying them one at a time). If this is the case, you can actually simplify your implementation a great deal by simply using 1 view controller with a single collection view inside it. Then, based on which set of data you want display, you just change what that collection view displays, either by swapping out the datasource object, or by just returning the other set of data in the delegate methods by checking which mode is activated. Then just call `reloadData` when the user taps the button to switch between datasets.